# Iterate through pandas data frame and replace some strings with numbers

Tags: pandas, dataframe, replace

I have a dataframe `sample_df` that looks like:

```
     bar   foo
0    rejected unidentified
1    clear    caution
2    caution    NaN
```

Note this is just a random made up df, there are lot of other columns lets say with different data types than just text. bar and foo might also have lots of empty cells/values which are NaNs.

The actual df looks like this, the above is just a sample btw:

```
|      |   Unnamed: 0 | user_id                          | result   | face_comparison_result   | created_at          | facial_image_integrity_result   | visual_authenticity_result   | properties      | attempt_id                       |
|-----:|-------------:|:---------------------------------|:---------|:-------------------------|:--------------------|:--------------------------------|:-----------------------------|:----------------|:---------------------------------|
|    0 |           58 | ecee468d4a124a8eafeec61271cd0da1 | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-20 17:50:43 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | 9e4277fc1ddf4a059da3dd2db35f6c76 |
|    1 |           76 | 1895d2b1782740bb8503b9bf3edf1ead | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-20 13:28:00 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | ab259d3cb33b4711b0a5174e4de1d72c |
|    2 |          217 | e71b27ea145249878b10f5b3f1fb4317 | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-18 21:18:31 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | 2b7f1c6f3fc5416286d9f1c97b15e8f9 |
|    3 |          221 | f512dc74bd1b4c109d9bd2981518a9f8 | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-18 22:17:29 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | ab5989375b514968b2ff2b21095ed1ef |
|    4 |          251 | 0685c7945d1349b7a954e1a0869bae4b | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-18 19:54:21 | caution                           | clear                        | {}              | dd1b0b2dbe234f4cb747cc054de2fdd3 |
|    5 |          253 | 1a1a994f540147ab913fcd61b7a859d9 | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-18 20:05:05 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | 1475037353a848318a32324539a6947e |
|    6 |          334 | 26e89e4a60f1451285e70ca8dc5bc90e | clear    | clear                    | 2017-06-17 20:21:54 | suspected                           | clear                        | {}              | 244fa3e7cfdb48afb44844f064134fec |
|    7 |          340 | 41afdea02a9c42098a15d94a05e8452b | NaN    | clear                    | 2017-06-17 20:42:53 | clear                           | clear                        | {}              | b066a4043122437bafae3ddcf6c2ab07 |
|    8 |          424 | 6cf6eb05a3cc4aabb69c19956a055eb9 | rejected    | NaN                    | 2017-06-16 20:00:26 |
```

I want to replace any strings I find with numbers, per the below mapping.

```
def no_strings(df):
  columns=list(df)
  for column in columns:
    df[column] = df[column].map(result_map)
#We will need a mapping of strings to numbers to be able to analyse later.
result_map = {'unidentified':0,"clear": 1, 'suspected': 2,"caution" : 3, 'rejected':4}
```

So the output might look like:

```
  bar  foo
0    4    0
1    1    3
2    3    NaN
```

For some reason, when I run `no_strings(sample_df)` I get errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show us the sample df and expected output

Comment: Sure, have edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['bar'] = df['bar'].map(result_map)
df['foo'] = df['foo'].map(result_map)
```

df

```
    bar foo
0   4   0
1   1   3
2   3   2
```

However, if you wish to be on the safe side (assuming a key/value is not in your result_map and you dont want to see a NaN) do this:

```
df['foo'] = df['foo'].map(lambda x: result_map.get(x, 'not found'))
df['bar'] = df['bar'].map(lambda x: result_map.get(x, 'not found'))
```

so an out put for this df

```
    bar           foo
0   rejected      unidentified
1   clear         caution
2   caution       suspected
3   sdgdg         0000
```

will result in:

```
   bar              foo
0   4                0
1   1                3
2   3                2
3   not found        not found
```

To be extra efficient:

```
cols = ['foo','bar','other_columns']
for c in cols:
   df[c] = df[c].map(lambda x: result_map.get(x, 'not found'))
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you edit for when you just want to cycle through the columns and you don't know they are called foo or bar? So you just want a function to do the edits to each cell you see that contains clear, unidentified etc and leave the existing cells the same?

Comment: @DhruvGhulati I added it in the post. See under 'to be extra efficient' ;)

Comment: This works! Only one thing, it doesn't leave the existing cells the same. if it finds a NaN then it replaces it with not found, but if the cell contains something like 8190909e566647a5b6afeee9b4ec6c6a it seems to turn it into an 'not found' for some reason. not found should only be for the blanks or the existing NaNs which were converted via np.nan

Answer (score 1):

Lets try  stack, map the dict and then unstack

```
df.stack().to_frame()[0].map(result_map).unstack()



    bar  foo
0    4    0
1    1    3
2    3    2
```

Comment: Sorry, I am writing `sample_df=sample_df.stack().to_frame()[0].map(result_map).unstack()` then `display(sample_df)`. All I see is a bump of NaNs and 0s.

Comment: Ok, does this help `df.drop(columns=cols).join(df.filter(items=cols).apply(lambda x: x.map(result_map)))`where `cols` are the columns you need mappings transferred.